# Why is there no charge in a capacitor connected to one battery pole?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, capacitance, batteries

Here is a very simple drawing of a battery pole and a capacitor plate connected by a wire (exaggerated in thickness).

[image]

**The question is**, why is the capacitor *not* being charged? But as you will see below, I feel that I can explain why it *should* get charged. So ultimately what I should rather ask is: **Where am I wrong in my understanding of moving charges?**

### **Here is my reasoning that the capacitor *should* become charged:**

- **Consider the battery alone**. The positive terminal is $a$. The positive and negative terminals are "charged" and creates an electric field $\vec E$ around them. A charge $q$ placed in the field would move, $E=F/q$.
- **We add a wire** to terminal $a$. Electrons in the wire are attracted to the positive $a$. Negative charge in the wire therefor moves towards $a$, and positive charge towards the other wire end $b$. At some point enough positive charge is build up at $b$ to cancel out the field $\vec E$ from the battery. Charges stop moving.
  The ideal proporty of the battery is that it will keep the terminal $a$ at a constant positive charge (by moving the incoming electrons away from $a$ to the opposite pole, by electromotive "force" $emf$). The charge at $a$ therefor remains constant and there is equally as much charge in the wire end $b$ as at the terminal $a$
- **We add a capacitor plate** $c$ at the wire end $b$. Since this is just to be considered as a new wire "end", this whole plate will have the same positive charge as the terminal $a$.
- **We add the second capacitor plate** $d$. There is a very small gab between $c$ and $d$. Because of the positive charge at $c$, electrons will be attracted and crowd up at the $d$ plate. This induced charge will be negative and equal in magnetude as the charge at $c$.
- **From $d$ to $e$** same story. $e$ should get a positive charge of equal magnetude as all the others.

Since we all know that an initially uncharged capacitor in an open circuit (which this clearly is) stays at *zero* potential difference, which means equal amount of charge on both plates, I don't see where I am wrong in this reasoning. If anyone can help me out, please do.

---

There is a [question here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103099/is-a-capacitor-in-an-open-circuit-charged) apparently asking the exact same thing. But the asker takes a different point of view (considers the open part as a second capacitor and the reasoning I follow is not given). Since my problem here is rather a misunderstanding somewhere in the understanding of charge behaviour and movements, I have made this into a new question.

Comment: close the circuit with a huge resistor $R$ and take the limit $R\to\infty$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a capacitor in an open circuit charged?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103099/)

Comment: @Phoenix87. Thanks for the comment. I get the point that there will flow no current. But in the beginning for a very short while, charges *will* flow. This is the part I am trying to describe. Can you tell me what I am misunderstanding in the reasoning above?

Comment: It is being charged, but only by a very small amount, similar to if you rub a cloth on glass and charge up a metal sphere, and then touch it to a neutral metal sphere.  The charge will equalize, causing a small brief current flow. But this is more of an electrostatics question than an electrical engineering question.

Comment: Battery will not give any positive charge to the plate since no negative charge is loosed from negative terminal.